# Local Security Authority Protection can't be switched on

Tags: windows, windows-11

I'm unable to switch on the new *Local Security Authority Protection* feature of Windows 11 (Version 22H2, Build 22621.1344).

"[image: Local Security Authority Protection]

Trying to [troubleshoot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/credentials-protection-and-management/configuring-additional-lsa-protection#:%7E:text=Analyze%20the%20results%20of%20event%203065%20and%20event%203066) it, in the Even Viewer I see a bunch of errors like this:

```
Code Integrity is unable to verify the image integrity of the file \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\fcon.dll because the set of per-page image hashes could not be found on the system.
```

Or:

```
Code Integrity determined that a process (\Device\HarddiskVolume3\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Platform\4.18.2211.5-0\MsMpEng.exe) attempted to load \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\iigd_dch.inf_amd64_3ad50285c3647623\igd10iumd64.dll that did not meet the Custom 3 / Antimalware signing level requirements.
```

But I don't see any events `3065` or `3066`.

Trying to repair Windows suggest I don't have any reported issues either:

```
❯ sfc /scannow

Beginning system scan.  This process will take some time.

Beginning verification phase of system scan.
Verification 100% complete.

Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.

❯ DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.22621.1

Image Version: 10.0.22621.1344

[==========================100.0%==========================] The restore operation completed successfully.
```

How do I fix this and enable Local Security Authority Protection?

Comment: Do you have the required `RunAsPPLBoot` and `RunAsPPL` registry keys set to the correct value? What do you have them set to?  I assume you have Windows 11 installed in UEFI mode? I also assume you have at least KB5022836 installed?

Comment: @Ramhound, I did not - tks, let me try it. Yes, it's a UEFI installation with BitLocker on. My Windows version is 22621.1344, isn't KB5022836 for 22000.1574?

Comment: @Ramhound I did have the `RunAsPPL` value but not `RunAsPPLBoot`. Adding the latter seems to have helped! Thank you, maybe you should post it as an answer.

Comment: I will have to find my source that made me ask that question to see if you had that key but you didn’t provide the value of the key you set it to

Comment: Sorry, KB5022845

Comment: I set it to 2, same as the other one.

Comment: I asked because of conflicting sources saying it should be 1 or 2, knew it should be one of those values, answer submitted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm unable to switch on the new Local Security Authority Protection feature of Windows 11 (Version 22H2, Build 22621.1344).

The following should solve your problem:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa]
"RunAsPPL"=dword:00000002
"RunAsPPLBoot"=dword:00000002
```

Source: [Turn On or Off Local Security Authority (LSA) Protection using REG file](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/enable-or-disable-local-security-authority-lsa-protection-in-windows-11.11104/)

Comment: See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/credentials-protection-and-management/configuring-additional-lsa-protection#how-to-disable-lsa-protection for an in-depth discussion of these settings.